# Dictionary value not getting changed

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict as below. My need is to check non-numeric value and update as numeric default.

```
d= {'A': inf, 'B': 0, 'C': inf, 'D': inf, 'E': 0}
```

Example:

```
if d['A']=='inf':
    d['A']=0
```

But this doesn't change the value, but same way I can change other key's value which are numeric. When checked the type of the key A

```
type(d['A'])
```

it gave result as float

```
<type 'float'>
```

How does the text have a float datatype here ?

Comment: have you set a variable to equal `A`? because `d[A] != d['A']`

Comment: sorry that's a typo, i have changed it. That's the Key

Comment: inf<anyObject>  not equal to 'inf'<string> so d['A'] == 'inf' is False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'inf' is a string where inf is actually a float.
if you want to use inf, you should use float('Inf').
thus, the right code would be
if d['A'] == float('Inf')

Comment: Thanks, want to understand how a text is stored as float,please elaborate

Comment: what do you mean? it's not stored as float, it's converted to float

Answer (score 1):

`'A'` isn't the same as `A`, and `'inf'` isn't the same as `inf` (note the quotes).

If `d = {'A': inf ...}` works, then what you want is:

```
if d['A'] == inf:
    d['A'] = 0
```

Comment: but this will result in undefined  errror

Comment: @D14: Hmm... either `inf` is defined or it isn't. Did you paste exactly the code you are using? There's no way `D = {'A': inf}` works, but `if D['A'] == inf: ...` on the next line would not.

Comment: yes thats the exact code.. solution provided as answer works..thanks

Comment: @D14: Oh did you get `{'A': inf}` from *printing* the dict? That would make sense. It's different than having it in your code. Unless somewhere you put `inf = ...` in one part of the code, and not in the other part